# Commas between your names, Why?

Tags: commas

My surname on my identity has a comma then states my first and middle names, why the comma after the surname?

Comment: Also [Why do we write the surname before the first name when writing someone's name?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324070/why-do-we-write-the-surname-before-the-first-name-when-writing-someones-name)

Answer (score 1):

It's a conventional way to make it clear that it isn't your first name, as in "Vane, Weather" and "Reeuwyk, Peter" especially in an official setting where the use of the first name is considered to be too informal, and is there to disinguish us from any other Vanes and Reeuwyks.

Comment: It's also used in lists where the sorting us by last name, or the last name is most important.

Comment: It's also just one convention. With French names it's common to capitalize the surname.